# PostgreSQL 9.5: запуск реплики

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5, репликация

Репликацию настраивал, но "пустых" серверов, без данных. Тут же - терабайт данных в исходном сервере: может какие-то есть осообенности.

Есть **PostgreSQL 9.5** и база на нём, размером около 1ТБ. На исходном (**Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, 192.168.2.1**): **9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04**; на реплике (**Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, 192.168.2.2**): **9.5.23-1.pgdg18.04+1**.

Задача: перенести на другой сервер в другой ДЦ.

Ограничения: канал 100 МБит, который нельзя занимать полностью (т.к. репликация будет идти долго).

Принятое решение: сделать сервер-реплику на новом месте и потом реплику перевести в Мастер.

Сделано:

1. на исходном сервере в добавлены параметры:

   ```
    wal_level = hot_standby
    max_wal_senders = 3
    wal_keep_segments = 128
    hot_standby = on
    synchronous_commit = remote_write
   ```

   Создан пользователь с правами репликации.
2. на реплике запущено "стягивание" исходной базы:

   ```
   time sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -P -R -X stream -r 5M -c fast -h 192.168.2.1 -U usereplica -D /pgdata/9.5/data && systemctl start postgresql
   ```

Первый раз запускал без старта сервиса postgresql, но когда подключился, то выяснилось, что **WAL** уже "ушёл": **requested WAL segment 000000010000010E00000048 has already been removed**.

Т.е. теперь я описываю вторую попытку, в которой специально сразу по завершению стягивания данных запускается реплика.

3. изначально **pg_basebackup** писал размер "**1005334619 kB**", а когда дошло до конца, то стянулось больше (**1007193125/1007193125 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace**) - вероятно это накопленные **WAL** подтянулись.
4. подключиться к серверу не удалось ("**systemctl status postgresql**" пишет "**Active: active (exited)**"):

   ```
    sudo -u postgres psql
    psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
   ```

   На мастере запустился процесс **wal_sender**, а на реплике **wal_receiver** - как и должно быть.
   На мастере

   ```
   select * from pg_stat_replication;
   ```

   показывает, что реплика есть (и данные ***_location** обновляются):

   ```
   postgres=# select * from pg_stat_replication;
      pid  | usesysid |  usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |        backend_start         | backend_xmin |   state   | sent_location | write_location | fl
    ush_location | replay_location | sync_priority | sync_state 
    -------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------
     21307 |  3150825 | usereplica | walreceiver      | 192.168.2.2  |                 |       42164 | 2020-09-22 07:50:40.76162+03 |              | streaming | 110/D068E068  | 110/D068E068   | 110/D068E068   | 110/D068E030    |             0 | async
    (1 row)
   ```
5. дописал в **recovery.conf** потом ещё пару параметров:

   ```
    trigger_file = '/tmp/failover_psql-slave_to_master'
    recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
   ```
6. в логах такие записи:

   ```
    LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2020-09-22 04:46:20 UTC
    LOG:  entering standby mode
    LOG:  redo starts at 110/B70DC680
    LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 110/B70E5328
    LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 78 at 110/B70E5328
    LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 110/B7000000 on timeline 1
    [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
    postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
   ```

С "**incomplete startup packet**" понятно: это, вероятно, проверка с **Zabbix**. А вот **"invalid resource manager ID**" - мне не понятен.

Как и "почему реплика не работает" (или работает не совсем "как надо").

Я не думаю, что проблема в различиях в минорных версиях. Хотя точно не могу знать.

Comment: `synchronous_commit = remote_write` - интересно бы знать "зачем"

Comment: Может не так понимаю: по мне это же "для надёжности".
Что я не понимаю?

Comment: Это для настройки синхронной репликации. При том только половина настройки синхронной репликации.

Answer (score 0):

> wal_keep_segments = 128

Мало. Очень мало. Зависит от объёмов записи на primary, конечно. Но это тот буфер, который позволяет хранить больше WAL чем нужно для самой базы и тем самым позволять репликам на некоторое время не забирать WAL, но и быть способными затем подключиться и продолжить работу. Предел в 2гб лаг для террабайтной базы поверх 100мбит сети - это выглядит мало.

> изначально pg_basebackup писал размер "1005334619 kB", а когда дошло до конца, то стянулось больше (1007193125/1007193125 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace) - вероятно это накопленные WAL подтянулись.

Это изменение размера самой базы. basebackup при указании опции вывода прогресса сначала запрашивает посчитать размер datadir, но база же продолжает работать и может увеличиваться.

> the database system is starting up

Это нормально. Реплика всегда в состоянии starting up. Начать принимать подключения и выполнять запросы может только если:

- прошли `consistent recovery state` - точка, на которую применили WAL больше чем самый новый блок из записанных на момент завершения копирования (или сбоя, что для старта реплики одно и то же) - нужно некоторое время до достижения `consistent recovery state reached`
- `standby_mode = on` в `recovery.conf` - это сделает `pg_basebackup -R` и видно по `entering standby mode`
- `hot_standby = on` в конфигурации базы - это вероятно не сделано. В 9.5 было выключено по-умолчанию.

```
LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 78 at 110/B70E5328
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 110/B7000000 on timeline 1
```

Несколько смущает, соглашусь, но странное сообщение от `startup` процесса перед `started streaming` лишь сигнализирует о том, что завершился последний из сохранённых локально WAL и был он сохранён не полностью - это нормально, `pg_basebackup` просто прервал его загрузку, будет дозагружен (фактически заново загружен) `walreceiver`'ом и продолжится восстановление.

> Я не думаю, что проблема в различиях в минорных версиях. Хотя точно не могу знать.

Реплика может быть по минорной версии новее мастера. Это рекомендуемый путь для минорных обновлений - сначала обновить реплики, затем мастер. Наоборот тоже возможно, но уже может приводить к неожиданностям.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. Много чего исправил, но основное было:  

> hot_standby = on

Я с репликацией в 9 версии почти не сталкивался (а сам - не настраивал) - не знал этих тонкостей.  
Хотел бы немного обсудить, если можно.  

> wal_keep_segments = 128  

Т.е., если у меня на одном проекте ожидается до 32 Гб (в теории) в сутки, то лучше как спланировать (для суточного лага):
- указать: wal_keep_segments = 2048
- как-то по другому, например, через max_wal_size / min_wal_size
И как оценить, на какой лаг лучше ориентироваться?

Много полезного узнал от вас - ещё раз спасибо. :-)

Comment: max_wal_size / min_wal_size - это настройки частоты чекпойнтов. Чекпойнт - это много io (и, к слову, wal после него т.к. работает full page writes). Но редкие чекпойнты надо учитывать, при старте базы после любого сбоя надо будет накатывать много wal. И такой незапланированный рестарт базы может занимать десятки минут.

Comment: Для отставания репликации: wal_keep_segments задирать (учитывайте что они хранятся всегда и нужно для них место на диске), replication slots (учтите, что неактичный слот репликации будет накапливать wal неограниченно вплоть до падения сервера из-за исчерпания всего доступного места. Соответствующая настройка для ограничения этого появилась в pg13 только), либо настраивать архивацию wal (что полезно с т.з. бекапов для pitr - но очень много места)